# Why does the var i begin with 0 in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I read a sample code `val asc = Array(5, { i -> (i * i).toString() })` .

The result is `["0", "1", "4", "9", "16"]`.

But I'm very strange why the var i begin with 0 in expression `{ i -> (i * i).toString() }`

Comment: Its an array index.. always start from 0

Comment: Out of interest, do you program in any other languages? For me, kotlin seems like an odd first choice.

Comment: @Bathsheba, curious as to why do feel Kotlin is an odd first choice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constructor you're using looks like this:

```
 /**
 * Creates a new array with the specified [size], where each element is calculated by calling the specified
 * [init] function. The [init] function returns an array element given its index.
 */
public inline constructor(size: Int, init: (Int) -> T)
```

It takes the index which **starts at `0`** for an array, thus `{ i -> (i * i).toString() }` with `0` as an argument results in `0`.

You can check it with this code if there's any doubt:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val func: (Int) -> (String) = { i -> (i * i).toString() }
    println(func(0))
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Arrays in Kotlin (like many languages including C, C++, C#, and Java) all use *zero based arrays*. This means the the first element is at position 0.

(Cf. Fortran where arrays are 1-based).